# SQL - SELECT all households by last value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, bigdata

I'm facing a problem that I cant wrap my head around so maybe you can help me to solve it!?

I have one table:

```
id | datetime           | property | house_id | household_id | plug_id | value
---+--------------------+----------+----------+--------------+---------+--------
1  |2013-08-31 22:00:01 | 0        | 1        | 1            | 1       | 15
2  |2013-08-31 22:00:01 | 0        | 1        | 1            | 3       | 3
3  |2013-08-31 22:00:01 | 0        | 1        | 2            | 1       | 21
4  |2013-08-31 22:00:01 | 0        | 1        | 2            | 2       | 1
5  |2013-08-31 22:00:01 | 0        | 2        | 1            | 3       | 53
6  |2013-08-31 22:00:02 | 0        | 2        | 2            | 4       | 34
7  |2013-08-31 22:00:02 | 0        | 1        | 1            | 1       | 16
...
```

The table holds electricity consumption measurements per second for multiple houses that have multiple households (apartments) in them. Each household has multiple electricity plugs. None of the houses or households have a unique id but are identified by a combination of house_id and household_id.

1) I need a SQL query that can give me a list of all the unique households.

2) I want to use the list from 1) to create a SQL query that gives me a list of the highest value for each household (the value is cumulative, so the latest datetime holds the highest value). I need a total value (SUM) for each household (sum of all the plugs in that household), i.e. a list of of households with their total electricity consumption.

Is this even possible? I'm using SQL Server 2012 and the table has 100.000.000 rows.

Comment: (1) Provide the results that you want for your sample data.  (2) Clarify the ambiguous meaning of "household_id".  Is it the column of that name?  Or is it the combination of the house and household ids?

Comment: Household_id is the column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the sum of the highest values of `value`, for house/household/plug combinations.  This may do what you want:

```
select house_id, household_id, sum(maxvalue)
from (select house_id, household_id, plug_id, max(value) as maxvalue
      from consumption
      group by house_id, household_id, plug_id
     ) c
group by house_id, household_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

according to your description I think you can use this query; 
`select house_id,household_id, max(value), sum(value) from your_table_name group by house_id,household_id`